# How to define a field that automatically takes the mean of all the data of another integer field of the model of which it is foreign key?

Tags: sql, django

I want this field to be predefined, and automatically calculate the average of all integer data in the field of which it is a foreign key.

Exemple :

```
class Product (models.Model):
    title = CharField(...)
    #this field set automatically the average, and also update after 
    #adding new  
    price_average = FloatField(...) 

class ProductItem (models.Model):
    title = CharField(...)
    price = IntegerField(...)
    _product = ForeignKey(Product)
```

is it possible in this way or do I have to implement a method that does it automatically in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can overwrite the save method of ProductItem to calculate the average of Product parent, like this.

```
class Product (models.Model):
    title = CharField(...)
    #this field set automatically the average, and also update after 
    #adding new  
    price_average = FloatField(...)

    def calculate_price_average(self):
        total = 0
        price = 0.0
        for item in self.items.all():
            total+=1
            price+=item.price
        self.price_average = price/total if total>0 else 0
        self.save()


class ProductItem (models.Model):
    title = CharField(...)
    price = IntegerField(...)
    _product = ForeignKey(Product, related_name='items')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductItem, self)save(*args, **kwargs):
        self._product.calculate_price_average()
```

So, when you save new product item to Product, the average change the value.